# Sample size calculation for paired binary proportion - non-inferiority study?

Tags: sample-size, binary-data, proportion, paired-data, non-inferiority

I want to conduct a retrospective study, validating an algorithm. My data will be something like the following:

| id | doctor | prediction |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| n | 0 | 1 |

My study design is non-inferiority, so I was thinking of using a two-sided two-sample test to test if the sensitivity of the algorithm is non-inferior to the doctor's assessment. I.e. I will be using the proportions to test this.
We assume that the doctor's assessments are correct - we do not have a ground truth.

My question is: how do I calculate the sample size for this?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: How can a predictor be "non-inferior to the truth" unless it is always the same? I would have thought you wanted data on "disease", "current predictor predictions", and "new predictor predictions" to see whether the new predictor was "non-inferior" to the current predictor when making predictions of the truth

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Henry. I tried to simplify in my post, but have now edited for further elaboration.
We have data on the currect predictor predictions - the doctor's assessments (what I before called "disease" for simplicity). We assume, however, that these are correct. It would be ideal to have the ground truth as an additional variable, however, this is not available.

Therefore, we want to test if the algorithm is non-inferior to the current standard, which is the doctor's assessments. I.e. performs the same or at least not more than 5% worse.